# Python; parse version number with dots from string via regex

Tags: python, regex

So I have this king of `string`:

```
some_string-1.4.2.4-RELEASE.some_extension
```

And I want to parse the version number (in my example: `1.4.2.4`)
But the number between the dots will not always be 1 digit, it could be something like: `1.40.2.4` or `11.4.2.4`.

This is what i have tried:

```
(\d+\.)?\d+\.\d+
```

And this does not parse all the numbers.

**EDIT**

I tried to use the answer from the duplicate link: `\d+(\.\d+)+`

And according to regex101 I get this result:

```
Full match  17-24   1.4.2.4
Group 1.    22-24   .4
```

But in my code I got only `.4`:

```
file_name = 'some_string-1.4.2.4-RELEASE.some_extension'

match = re.findall('\d+(\.\d+)+', file_name)
if len(match) == 0:
    print('Failed to match version number')
else:
    print(match[0])
    return match[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider the following pattern :

```
file_name = 'some_string-1.4.2.4-RELEASE.some_extension'

pattern = r'\-([0-9.-]*)\-'
match = re.findall(pattern, file_name)
if len(match) == 0:
    print('Failed to match version number')
else:
    print(match[0])
```

output:

> 1.4.2.4

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern is almost right.

Use

```
(\d+(?:\.\d+)+)
```

This changes the first group to be the entire version number, and ignore the internal repeating group.

```python
str = "some_string-1.4.2.4-RELEASE.some_extension"
regex = r'''(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)'''
print(re.findall(regex, str))  # prints ['1.4.2.4']
```

Answer (score 0):

The pattern `\d+(\.\d+)+` contains a repeating capturing group and will contain the value of the last iteration which is `.4` and will be returned by findall.

If you would make it a non capturing group it will match the whole value but also values like 1.1 and 9.9.9.99.9.9

```
\d+(?:\.\d+)+
```

If the digits must consists of 3 dots and between hyphens, you might use a capturing group:

```
-(\d+(?:\.\d+){3})-
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yZOKZD/1)

Or use lookarounds to get a match without using a group:

```
(?<=-)\d+(?:\.\d+){3}(?=-)
```